# I changed my Firebase rules to all authenticated users.. What I need to change in requests (Flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I changed my rules to give access to all authenticated users with this:

```dart
rules_version = '2';
// Allow read/write access on all documents to any user signed in to the application
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

And this is an example of query

```dart
      await databaseReference
          .collection("lab_${pathSlashless}_url")
          .get()
          .then //......
```

What I need to change to adapt my gets to the new rule?

I need change in every get? or in one place only?

Comment: Do u have the code to login / sign up with `FirebaseAuth`?

Comment: I don't know, but the login in my app is through another Database. In Firebase I store only few things

Comment: @AdaLovelassy if your not using the firebase auth. Maybe you should remove that rules

Comment: So my db is secure if I keep the original rules?

Comment: Well, technically, they won't be able to access or change the database if they don't have the link to your database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... Then you'll probably have to login to firebase also. For this, just go through the Authentication tab in firebase. The instructions are clear on that. After that, you have to add `firebase_auth` and `firebase_core` packages to ur `pubspec.yaml`.

Once you've done all this, you can move on to authenticating the user.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as auth;

final auth.FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth;

Future<void> signIn() {
  final String token = yourSignInMethod_s_Token();
  // Basically, any unique String value for each user
    try {
    await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCustomToken(token).catchError(onError);
    // Or you can do authentication with any other method, like email/password
    // phone number, etc. Just read up of the auth error codes for those
    // in case of errors like shown below.
  } on auth.FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    if (e.code == 'custom-token-mismatch') {
    } else if (e.code == 'invalid-custom-token') {
    } else {}
  }
}
```

Comment: If it is email/password, you'll first have 2 options. Create a new user, or sign in that user, so better to have 2 different functions for that, aka login and sign up.

Comment: On second thought, going for log in and sign up would be better, unless u or ur client has a privacy issue

Comment: I would like to know, in my case as I have the credentials in another db, can I keep the default rules?

Comment: @AdaLovelassy As long as people don't have your `google-services.json` file or any of its contents, I think its fine. But its safe to be prepared, just in case. But that's up to you. If you're doing this for a client, then I highly recommend that you don't have the default rules

Comment: the google-services.json is in the project structure

Comment: I mean, as long as "people who might try to sabotage your app" don't have the `google-services.json` file, lol.